# How to deactivate a check box based on the text on that column in msacess

Tags: ms-access

> I have a form and in the form there is a  filed called Operation and there is a check box for each row of data.I want to disable the check box for that row where ever the Operation row data is "DELETED"
>
> I tried in on current event and on load event of form but it din't work out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have handled it in a different way by setting properties in macro.